# How to run two processes at once JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

How to run a process in background while another process will be a User GUI which will manipulate all gathered information in background?

Comment: i guess u need lightweight processes called threads.

Answer (score 1):

### You Could...

Use a `Thread`, which will allow you to execute code in the background.

See [Lesson: Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) for more details.

You could even use an `Executor` of some kind if you have a number of tasks you want to run...

### You Could...

Use a `SwingWorker` if you are using Swing and want to run long running process in the background and safely interact with the UI

See [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

### You Could

Make use of the concurrency support in JavaFX if that's what you're using.  See [Concurrency in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) for more details...

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for so called Threads. They can be used in various ways in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

In case of the GUI you also have to use the SwingUtilities with invokeNow/invokeLater to update the GUI from within a thread.